# Regular expression for javascript function getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have following similar pieces of code:

```
document.getElementById('caption1').onclick = function () {
    window.open("#abstract1","_self");
    if(document.getElementById('abstract1').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('abstract1').style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('abstract1').style.display = "none";                            
    }

};
document.getElementById('caption2').onclick = function () {
    window.open("#abstract2","_self");
    if(document.getElementById('abstract2').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('abstract2').style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('abstract2').style.display = "none";                            
    }

};
document.getElementById('caption3').onclick = function () {
    window.open("#abstract3","_self");
    if(document.getElementById('abstract3').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('abstract3').style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('abstract3').style.display = "none";                            
    }

};
```

The code goes on so till 9. Instead of writing so many similar pieces of code how can I just write one which will work for. Perhaps I should write some Regex but how?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think regex would help here. What you could do is replace the 9 similar blocks with one block inside a for loop. Or you could use a delegated event handler on a parent element, and within that handler check the id of the clicked element.

Comment: I recommend using event delegation on a containing div.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, just the OP incorrectly suggested using RegEx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate a variable with your string.  Also taking @squints advice of using a function instead of creating a dozen anonymous function objects

```
someFunction(){
  var id = "abstract" + this.id.substr(7);
  window.open("#" + id,"_self");

  el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = (el.style.display === 'none') ? '' : "none";
}

for( var x = 0; x < 10; x++ ){
  document.getElementById('caption' + x).onclick = someFunction;
}
```

Comment: `x` won't be the value you expect. Use `this` instead.

Comment: @squint Good catch, I'll fix it

Comment: +1 Only thing I'd suggest removing the function from the loop so that you're not creating multiple function objects. But that's not such a big deal.

Comment: I didn't notice that the `.style` was a different element from the one bound. But you can use the `num` variable with `getElementById` to solve the original problem. `var el = document.getElementById("abstract" + num)`

Comment: Thanks squint and @Gary for helping out